# Advanced Search Box Web Part Redirect

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, advanced-search

Is it possible to configure multiple result pages for advanced search box web-part SharePoint?

[image]

By default there's only 1 result page present. I want to add few conditions here if possible. It should direct to a page depending on the search query. For example :

Case 1:
If search query= "Type of File" = 'Research Paper' then take to "ResearchPaperResultPage.aspx"

Case 2: 
If search query= "Type of File" = 'HR Policy' then take to "HRPolicyResultPage.aspx"

Context is : SharePoint 2013 online.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own search result pages as [search verticals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794227.aspx). In these pages, you can edit the search query per your requirements.